# How can I cut long text according to available div area size?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a text and preview div area. Whenever I have put long text on the div area, it is overflowed out of div area. I have tried `text-wrap:normal`, but it does not cut the context and showed only what text fit to the available area.

How can I cut long text according to available div area size? Afterwards, I will put css read more button to end of preview text area.

Comment: You should add an example with the relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, that when combined with `overflow: hidden` and one-line technique `white-space: nowrap` adds a `...` at the end of the text, containing it within the parent's width:

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  my very long text is here my very long text is here
</div>
<a href="">[Continue to read]</a>
```

Comment: Instead of putting ... to end of text, I want to add "continue to read". Where should I put this text? And, I have surprised about, stackoverflow can run snippet.

Comment: @Hevan, the `...` are the default for `text-overflow`. If you don't want it, just remove that property, and the text will simply be hidden.

Comment: @Hevan - I've editted the answer, setting the `div` as float left, and placing a simple anchor for "continue to read". The floating will give you the looks that you want!

Comment: IS there a way to put "continue to read" automatically to end of text? Or, are there any third-party library which cuts long text and puts the mentioned text to end of div?

Comment: Yes, but I have marked as right answer. I just want do those things **automatically**.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add overflov:hidden style for preview container so the text what will be after container won't be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow: hidden` property. The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible:

```
#preview-div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```